# Why is the host command returning both an A and a CNAME record?

Tags: domain-name-system, cache

We have a zone with a 2 hour TTL.  Previous to making any changes it returned an `A` record when looking up the entry for `www`.

We changed the entry for `www` to point to a `CNAME` record.  After the change, we noticed that the host command was returning both a `CNAME` and an `A` record as shown:

```
user@osx:~$ host www.example.com
www.example.com has address 192.168.1.2
www.example.com is an alias for vip.example.com.
www.example.com is an alias for vip.example.com.
user@osx:~$
```

Was this a problem with some DNS servers caching?  If we had simply let the TTL fully expire, would we have gotten a `CNAME` as expected with no `A` record?

I didn't get any more detailed information with dig or other commands.

**EDIT:** The true address for `vip.example.com.` is completely different from the `A` record that was originally returned:

```
user@osx:~$ host vip.example.com
vip.example.com has address 172.16.4.5
user@osx:~$
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does a `dig +trace` show anything? It should show how it comes to the response you're getting.

Comment: We have rolled back the change as this was affecting a production site.  I did not run 'dig +trace' when I encountered this problem, but if I see the problems again, I shall run 'dig'.  We plan to attempt this change again later today.

Comment: +1 dig is a much better utility to use. Even just `dig www.example.com` will confirm for you what you are looking for.

Comment: The second attempt at changing DNS was successful.  `dig +trace` and `host` both showed things functioning as expected.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I'm aware, this is perfectly normal. Querying a `CNAME` returns the value of the `A` record, because this is ultimately where it's mapping to, when you're querying for an `A` record.

Being a Windows guy, I use `nslookup`. When the query type is set to `A` I get:

```
Server:  bladedc1.live.local
Address: 192.168.163.50

Name:    example.com.au
Address:  x.x.x.x
Aliases:  www.example.com.au
```

But when I set the query type to `CNAME` I get:

```
www.example.com.au
Server:  bladedc1.live.local
Address: 192.168.163.50

Non-authoritative answer:
www.example.com.au        canonical name = example.com.au

example.com.au    internet address = x.x.x.x
```

Try setting the query type to `CNAME` instead of `A` and see what you get.

Comment: +1. AFAIK, this is correct. A DNS client will, as Farseeker has stated, return both the CNAME and A record as they're essentially "attached" to each other. When using CNAME records you ultimately only need to worry about the TTL of the A record as the CNAME record is simply an alias for the A record, and as such, is not going to change (unless you also change the CNAME record).

Answer (score 0):

```
kechara# host cnametest.flame.org
cnametest.flame.org is an alias for www.isc.org.
www.isc.org has address 149.20.64.42
www.isc.org has IPv6 address 2001:4f8:0:2::d
```

Host is smart.  It tries to display all the data it can to the user.  However, `dig` is a much more reliable debugging tool.

Answer (score 0):

You should first identify whether or not the response you are getting starts at the nameservers or is further down the chain.

```
$ host -t ns example.com
example.com name server b.iana-servers.net.
example.com name server a.iana-servers.net.
$ host example.com b.iana-servers.net
Using domain server:
Name: b.iana-servers.net
Address: 193.0.0.236#53
Aliases: 

example.com has address 192.0.32.10
$ host example.com a.iana-servers.net.
Using domain server:
Name: a.iana-servers.net.
Address: 192.0.34.43#53
Aliases: 

example.com has address 192.0.32.10
```